# Embed a tweet in a blogdown post

Tags: r, twitter, hugo, blogdown, hugo-shortcode

I want to embed a tweet with an image. When I embed a tweet on a blogdown post using shortcodes it does not appear in the twitter style

For example using the shortcode:

```
{{< tweet 989470885475008512 >}}
```

I get an output (my blogdown uses the academic theme)

[image]

rather than this (as shown in the blogdown [guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/content.html#shortcode))...

[image]

Is there a way to override this behavior to get the appearance like this second example or to embed a tweet following the dev titter [guidelines](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets) (which when I paste the html code in gives output like the first image above).

I am guessing, but I think the loss of twitter style in the embedded tweet restricts the possibility to embed a tweet with an image (it gives similar output to the first example along with the image url).

**UPDATE**

This is a browser (Firefox) issue (as suggested by @hplieninger). The twitter style appears when viewing the page in Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried to open the blog post using different browsers with different settings? I sometimes observe the same thing, but I think it is related to my restrictive Firefox privacy-setup.

Comment: I've also found RStudio doesn't render it completely in its viewer. Try opening it via a browser.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
blogdown::shortcode('tweet', '989470885475008512')
```
````

Should work.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that just   {{% tweet 1281252614349426689 %}} will work. If you wanted a slightly lighter syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of copying the `id` of the tweet, simply click the drop-down icon at the top-right of the tweet, then select "Embed Tweet", copy the code and paste it into your markdown post. Go to your browser and you should see the effect.

[image]